# Android AsyncTask onPostExecute won't display AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I'm having an issue with my onPostExecute from an AsyncTask class. Here is the code.

**--EDIT: added in the rest of the code by request--**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    preliminaryTasks();
}

private void preliminaryTasks() {

    //removed more code

    new discoverAddresses().execute();

}

public class discoverAddresses extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<String>> {

    @Override
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params){

        /* Lots of code here taken out */

        List<String> addresses = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Added for debugging purposes
        addresses.add("http://192.168.1.120:80");
        addresses.add("http://192.168.1.110:80");
        return addresses;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> addresses){

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                MainActivity.this.finish();
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        MainActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        return; 

    }
}
}
```

But the alert dialog never shows up; when I watch in the debugger it will execute the alert.show() line but it never displays on the UI. Does anyone have any ideas on why this is? Thanks!

**EDIT: both AlertDialogs get executed in the debugger but never display on the UI**

**EDIT2: I copied just the code I posted here (to see if it was the removed code I took out for simplification that was causing the issue) into a new project and the alertdialog actually appears, meaning the code I took out is an issue. This is coming up in LogCat in my original project upon Force Close termination of the app.**

```
02-02 11:13:28.746: D/AndroidRuntime(11658): Shutting down VM
02-02 11:13:28.746: W/dalvikvm(11658): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40fce300)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2257)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4899)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
02-02 11:13:28.762: E/AndroidRuntime(11658):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Looks like the context might not be right. You need to pass the right context to AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this), instead of MainActivity.this.

Comment: @Leco I am not sure I know what you mean.

Comment: Seems that you have a problem with a listView and not with asyncTask  . You should show us some more code that you use for the listView instead.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I can't find the keyword "ListView" in any of my full code. Is there something specific I should be looking for?

Comment: Well that is odd . The logs say that there is an error with a listView , on its adapter's getView() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem with my code. At some point this method, promptAddresses was being called. It has its own separate AlertDialog. Because the addressArray had an index of 5 it was screwing with the AlertDialog.builder because three of the indexes were null.

**TLDR: Don't have any null values in a string array when dealing with AlertDialog.Builders**

SOLUTION: final String[] addressArray = new String[**addresses.size()**];

Thank you very much to everyone who helped. I apologize for not giving the full code and confusing the whole problem. At any rate, your answers still helped very much.

```
public String promptAddresses(List<String> addresses){
    final String[] addressArray = new String[5];
    int i = 0;

    Iterator it = addresses.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String next = (String) it.next();
        addressArray[i] = next;
        Log.i("ADDRESSES", next);
        i++;
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Pick your address");
    builder.setItems(addressArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    AlertDialog alert =  builder.create();
    alert.show();

    return hubAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this works for me, in OnPostExecute Method.

I add Activity object as propretie in my AsyncTask Class  which I instantiate in the constructor of that AsyncTack so that I can call that activity and perform runOnUiThread in  onpostexe...

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity);
            builder.setTitle("Connection ?");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            builder.setMessage("Test \n ");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok",null);
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            Activity.runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    //show AlertDialog
                    alert.show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: The [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) method already runs on UIThread, so there's no need to wrap the code to show the dialog with `runOnUiThread`.

Answer (score 0):

I watch your code but can't find any trouble. Did you executes the `AsyncTask` in the main Thread? If not, you may wrap follows code for show the `AlertDialog`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runable(){
    public void run(){
        //show AlertDialog
    }
})
```

Comment: `onPostExecute()` runs in the UI Thread already. No need for `runOnUIThread()`.

Comment: My AsyncTask is being called from the main thread. But just to try, I added in the 'runOnUiThread' code. It looks like this. "MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runable(){..." But for some reason it does not recognize 'runOnUiThread'. Eclipse wants me to create a method out of it. MainActivity does extend Activity. This is weird, any ideas?

Comment: @A--C right, no need for `runOnUIThread()`. I got success for try your code, so weird.

Comment: I forgot the extra "n" in Runnable. That solved the issue of it not being recognized by Eclipse. But even with the runOnUiThread, it skips executing the code and just walks past it without every showing it on the UI.

Comment: @BarryBostwick, could you show more about your code? How did you define and execute the `AsyncTask`

Comment: @BarryBostwick It's odd that the debugger says `show()` is called but nothing's happening. Can you make the same type of dialog in `onCreate()` and see if that works? And as Cheney wrote, post your full AsyncTask.

Comment: I added the exact same AlertDialog block of code to the onCreate() and it successfully showed up in the UI. The onPostExecute() AlertDialogs still did not appear.

Comment: I noticed in your onPostExecute that you did not `@override` it

Comment: @Matt Good eye! Unfortunately, it did not fix my problem.

Comment: try it without the `MainActivity.this.run...` in the onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your code for the doInBackground() function:

```
List<String> addresses = null;
//Added for debugging purposes
addresses.add("http://192.168.1.120:80");
```

This will generate a Null exception on the second line because addresses is null and will therefore terminate your thread.

Comment: Thank you for noticing this. I forgot to add in the "= new ArrayList<String>;" in my version of the post. My actual code in Eclipse does have that bit. It does not break at that part unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there may be problem in your `actvity_main.xml`. I tried your provided code by taking blank `RelativeLayout` The code works fine it shows two alertdialog along with coded functionality. Just try same and track the error

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```